# How to import *.zip projct into netbeans installed on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I was used to program on Windows in NetBeans. I was forced to use Ubuntu instead of Windows. I have created project.zip file in NetBeans on Windows. Now, I would like to import this file into NetBeans on Ubuntu.

Could you kindly advice me how to import zipped project into NetBeans on Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to unzip your project into your netbeans folder on Ubuntu and then open the project from within netbeans.

Comment: So there is no possibility to import whole zip like in MS Windows?

Comment: I believe that in order for that functionality to work on Ubuntu you have to install some additional libraries. I would just unzip it and then import it. It's probably easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will do it this way.